# How do you weight a chi square for uncertainties in $x$ and $y$ (different units)?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

So I have experimental data for energy vs angle with uncertainties in both the $x$ and $y$ direction for every point. I am comparing this to a known curve/data points. Is it possible to calculate a chi square value that accounts for errors in both values. Ideally this would be using a piece of code in Python.

I am also open to any other methods of testing goodness of fit that can account for both sets of uncertainties.

Comment: Do you know the size of these uncertainties? If so, you can express errors as standard values, whose squares' sum is a $\chi^2$ test statistic if the errors are independent Gaussians.

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I do know the size of each. What do you mean by standard values?

Comment: Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models

Comment: There is no unique best solution for fitting when both x and y have uncertainties, but orthogonal distance regression is a good choice that is available in python ([scipy.odr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html)).